# capistrano - git ls-remote -h doesn't have the git url

Tags: git, capistrano3

I'm new to using Capistrano. I set it up correctly, but when I run cap staging deploy I get this -

```
DEBUG [b678d5eb] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/myproj/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  )
DEBUG [b678d5eb]    usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]  [-u <exec> | --upload-pack <exec>] <repository> <refs>...
DEBUG [b678d5eb] Finished in 0.325 seconds with exit status 129 (failed).
```

I think the git clone url should follow after the -h, but I'm not sure.

I'm using Capistrano 3.2.1. Here's my deploy.rb -

```
lock '3.2.1'
set :application, 'myproj'
set :repository, 'https://vrao@git.test.com/scm/~vrao/myproj.git'
set :scm_passphrase, 'blah'
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `git clone` URL should follow after the `-h`, but I'm not sure.

Indeed, and you have found why that URL was empty in your case (wrong capistrano version)

And the usage message is, in this case (`-h`, [meaning `--heads`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt--h), *without* URL) expected.

This is documented with Git 2.25.2 (March 2020).
Both "`git ls-remote -h`" and "`git grep -h`" give short usage help, like any other Git subcommand, but it is not unreasonable to expect that the former would behave the same as "`git ls-remote --head`" (there is no other sensible behavior for the latter).

> The documentation has been updated in an attempt to clarify this.

See [commit 1ff466c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ff466c018692d0ac7c5f30a449632659e87a73b) (27 Feb 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cdef998](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdef998b4619cb9acfe2955fcbe9db0ea2f46d33), 11 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ff466c018692d0ac7c5f30a449632659e87a73b): clarify that `-h` alone stands for `help`
>
> We seem to be getting new users who get confused every 20 months or so with this "`-h` consistently wants to give help, but the commands to which `-h` may feel like a good short-form option want it to mean something else." compromise.
>
> Let's make sure that the readers know that **`git cmd -h` (with no other arguments) is a way to get usage text**, even for commands like `ls-remote` and `grep`.
>
> Also extend the description that is already in `gitcli.txt`, as it is clear that users still get confused with the current text.

The [`git ls-remote` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ff466c018692d0ac7c5f30a449632659e87a73b/Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt#L24-L33) now  includes:

> Note that `git ls-remote -h` used without anything else on the command line **gives help, consistent with other git subcommands**.

And [gitcli](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ff466c018692d0ac7c5f30a449632659e87a73b/Documentation/gitcli.txt#L124-L127):

> Note that some subcommand (e.g. [`git grep -h xxx`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--h)) may behave differently when there are things on the command line other than `-h`, but `git subcmd -h` without anything else on the command line is meant to consistently give the usage.

Answer (score 11):

Never mind, I was following the documentation for capistrano 2x, while I have 3.2.1 installed.

For anyone who might face the same issue, in capistrano 2x you specify the git repo by setting the repository variable, while in 3x it's been changed to repo_url. I changed it and now it works fine. Here's the documentation I would recommend to follow for 3x -
http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/