# Capistrano 3 to ubuntu 14.04 git error

Tags: git, ubuntu, capistrano3

My capistrino check failed due to git error on ubuntu server.

Got this log

```
$ cap staging deploy:check --trace 
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO[bf639f43] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/zarapp/ on 54.169.61.155
DEBUG[bf639f43] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/zarapp/
INFO[bf639f43] Finished in 1.368 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUGUploading /tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFOUploading /tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO[c06c1df0] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh on 54.169.61.155
DEBUG[c06c1df0] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh
INFO[c06c1df0] Finished in 0.162 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  on 54.169.61.155
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  )
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]     usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]  [-u <exec> | --upload-pack <exec>]
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]     
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]                          [-q|--quiet] [--exit-code] [--get-url] [<repository> [<refs>...]]
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e] Finished in 0.462 seconds with exit status 129 (failed).
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 54.169.61.155: exit
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `exit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SystemExit: exit
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `exit'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check
```

I thought this is the error with the git on server.I have updated it but no still no success.
I ssh to server and tried to run `git ls-remote -h`  command directly

```
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/zarapp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h  )
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]     usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]  [-u <exec> | --upload-pack <exec>]
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]     
DEBUG[d6b0ae0e]                          [-q|--quiet] [--exit-code] [--get-url] [<repository> [<refs>...]]
```

it also says the same output. Is the capistrino 3 is running the wrong syntax for command or there is some other issue ?

Comment: this solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938297/capistrano-git-ls-remote-h-doesnt-have-the-git-url

Comment: Excellent. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) needs a repo to operate on.

that means:

- `git ls-remote -h` will always fails
- but this would work:

  ```
    git ls-remote -h /local/path/to/a/repo
    git ls-remote -h origin
  ```

---

As the [OP Hemc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1539932/hemc) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083007/capistrano-3-to-ubuntu-14-04-git-error/26083097#comment40870796_26083007): "[capistrano - `git ls-remote -h` doesn't have the git url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941743/6309)" does point out to a capistrano  version mismatch (2.x vs. 3.x)

See "[Preparing Your Application](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/)"

> The **`deploy.rb`** is a place where the configuration common to each environment can be specified, normally the repository URL and the user as whom to deploy are specified here.

```
set :application, 'my app name'
    set :repo_url, 'git@example.com:me/my_repo.git'
    ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }
```

The `git ls-remote` will use **`repo_url`** for its execution.

Comment: Thanks Vonc, but i am running this command inside the git repo and how can i tell capistrino to run this command with remote ?